# UNIX\LINUX: How to add a directory text to each line inside a file?

Tags: linux, unix, csh

UNIX\LINUX: How to add a directory text to each line inside a file?

NOTE: I am just using shell(CMD TOOL OF LINUX REDHAT EPIC) no other...

You see I have many log files(.txt.gz) and I was able to open all of them just by using:

```
foreach i (./*/*dumpfiles.txt.gz_*)
> foreach? zcat $i
> foreach? grep "-e" $i
> foreach? END
```

Meaning I am going through all those folders finding a file *dumpfiles.txt.gz_*

The the output is like:

```
0x4899252 move x -999
0x4899231 move y -0
0x4899222 find scribe
0x4899231 move x -999
```

etc..

The problem is that I need the directory to be set to each line of the file...
I could get the directory by the command pwd.

**The question to my problem is how to add a directory name on each line of the file?**
Example:

```
(directory) (per line of all files)
machine01   0x4899252 move x -999
machine01   0x4899231 move y -0
machine09   0x4899222 find scribe
machine09   0x4899231 move x -999
```

etc..

I tried using $ sed but I cant find the solution... :(

Thanks...

Comment: What shell is this? That's not sh syntax.

Comment: That's csh syntax, probably tcsh given the continuation prompt

Comment: Sirs, its just a command using unix cmd tool...

Comment: Do you have the `zgrep` tool? It does this already. `zgrep something */*/filename`

Comment: Ohh yes sir, I used it just now and it prints the lines like base on the grep condition... Sir How about adding a directory after or before printing a line that grep is printing?.. Must I use something like a pipe '|' ? :( I tried pwd | zgrep "(word)" $i  But didn't work... :(

Answer (score 1):

here's a little perl script that does what you ask for (input is the filename):

```
$file = shift;
$path = `pwd`;
chomp($path);
open(TRY, "< $file");
while ($line = <TRY>) { print ($path . $line);}
close(TRY);
```

of course this prints to the screen, but you can pour it to file and rename it at the end of the script to `$file`

if you want to run it on the entire dir and downyou can run

```
find . -exec scriptname {} \;
```

if you want it to be on the current dir only, you need to add a `-maxdepth 1` flag to the `find` after the '.'

**update:**

this also works (with no script, just a shell line):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^/$ENV{PWD} /g'
```