# UNIX: How to add a "DIRECTORY" each line of a text file using sed?

Tags: unix

UNIX: How to add a "DIRECTORY" each line of a text file using sed? At this beginning of the line if possible? Thanks...
**(Using Unix / Linux Command tool)**

I have been using foreach loop and sed together, and what is now missing is just a directory each line which I am still trying to figure out... Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please add some sample input and output.

Comment: Do you want the word "DIRECTORY" or the file's directory at the beginning of each line?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16803855/970195

Comment: Sirs, sorry for that. I wanted to add the directory folder / path. Thanks so much all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking just to add the word "DIRECTORY" then the following should be fine:

```
sed 's/^/DIRECTORY /' inputfile
```

If you are looking to add a path then I would recommend to change the delimiter.

```
sed 's,^,'$PWD' ,' inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir Jaypal. I will apply this right away. I was looking for that added path.. Thanks. I'll update this if its ok. :)

Comment: Sir Jay, the output was great, it printed the directory, now I have a new problm, it actually printed the folder which logically is correct but how if I am using

    foreach i (./*/filedump.txt.gz*)
    foreach? zcat $i | sed 's,^,'$PWD','

It outputs still the folder where you are, how if I wanted to print the folder of the output content of the file?
If I confuse you its like this:
I am @ /dummy/ and inside that folder I am file1 & file2 folders with diffrent txt files.
So while foreach is providing line outputs of a file I wish I could print the directory of the file its printing.

Comment: $PWD was just an example. For your loop use `${i%.*}` and you should get path of your file prefixed.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir Jaypal! :) I appreciated it so much, you are a life saver thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome @MegaManX. Just Jaypal is fine. :) This site is excellent when you post your question in detail along with what have you tried to to solve the problem. Good luck.

Comment: (MASTER JAYPAL). I tried **zcat $i | sed '/s/^/'${i%.*}', '** and the output is **missing }**... :( Have I done something wrong? And thanks for the advice. :) I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Post your complete one-line with the for loop.

Comment: **foreach i (./*/*dumpfiles*)**
    foreach? **zcat $i | sed '/s/^/'${i%.*}', '**
    foreach? **end**

Comment: Jaypal, @Jaypal This is the code, sorry I cant use next line on this page maybe because of the **bold**

Comment: Yeah its really weird I even tried without the bracket **zcat $i | sed '/s/^/'$i%.*','** and it say no sed: no match many times...

Master, can I see your sample code? Maybe I just have a typo stuff... :(